# OSX - passing midiReadProc results to the main thread in C

Tags: macos, core-audio, coremidi

I have the following program structure in OSX/Darwin:

Producer thread generates data and feeds it to a circular buffer.

Consumer real-time CoreAudio thread renders the data from circular buffer into DAC.

They are coordinated by means of dispatch_semaphores.

Producer thread parameters can be controlled by the GUI (GLUT, non-Cocoa)
or by MIDI.

As far as controlling the producer form the GUI is concerned, things work pretty well.

However, ***midiReadProc( )*** callback "lives" on its own real time thread, from which the producer thread
should neither be controlled nor notified, but MIDI data should somehow get passed to the main thread instead, 
from which the producer thread should get enqueued and updated.

Are there any ways of doing this without being too OSX specific?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this is might be to use a lock-free circular fifo for the incoming MIDI data.  The audio producer thread can then poll this fifo before generating the next batch of data for the real-time consumer.

Comment: Thanks. I'd prefer keeping **as away of iOS** as possible, and closer to common UNIX if possible. I had a sonification utility which worked as devised for as long as producing data stayed on the CA render thread. Unfortunatley, this overtaxed the render thread while keeping 11 other logical cores almost idle. As soon as I managed splitting and parallelizing the producer off the render thread, MIDI reader which contains a rather sophisticated data filtering sooner or later crashes the circular buffer even if using `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()..)` for moving relevant data out of it.

Comment: A lock-free consumer should not require a dispatch.  How to do cross-platform hard real-time threading in UNIX or Linux (if even possible) is a whole different question.

Comment: Thanks. The consumer of (interpreted) MIDI information here must be the producer, which may wait on a dispatch_semaphore_wait, signaled from the (real time) CA consumer render thread. I'm not after strict "hard" syncing requirements in this phase, but rather trying to find the simplest solution in which updating a few values from MIDI need not cause data corruption or make the circular buffer between (non-CA) producer and CA consumer crash prone...

Comment: A lock-free fifo consumer shouldn't have any reason to crash.  It should just be reading from pre-allocated memory.

Comment: Thanks for encouraging my moving on the right track in the right direction!

Comment: How do you ensure the MIDI thread can safely write to the ring buffer and not run into concurrency issues -- without blocking the MIDI thread? Any synchronization variable written by the MIDI thread must eventually be read by the other thread...

Comment: You don't write safely.  Only atomically.  You make the lock free circular buffer big enough that if you have to synchronize, the app has already failed.

Answer (score 1):

The way I to do it is to use a ring buffer and copy those midi messages on to the ring buffer in the callback. Then on the main thread, poll the ring buffer and process the data.